# Is there a way to create a cross-region read only replica of an RDS instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-rds

I need to create a read only replica in a different region via Ansible.

The [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/rds_module.html) don't seem to mention if this is possible. They only mention normal read only replicas:

```
# Create a read-only replica and wait for it to become available
- rds:
    command: replicate
    instance_name: new-database-replica
    source_instance: new_database
    wait: yes
    wait_timeout: 600
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating cross region replicas it works pretty much exactly the same as creating normal read replicas except that instead of specifying the instance identifier you must specify the full ARN. This then means that if you have a source instance called `my-mysql-instance` in US East 1 in the account `123456789012` then your ARN (and so `instance_name` parameter to the RDS module) will look like this:

```
arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:123456789012:db:my-mysql-instance
```

So you just need to adapt the replicate task from the docs to be something like this:

```
- rds:
    command: replicate
    region: eu-west-1
    instance_name: new-database-replica
    source_instance: arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:123456789012:db:my-mysql-instance
    wait: yes
    wait_timeout: 600
```

This will create a new read replica in EU West 1 (Ireland) called `new-database-replica` from a source database instance called `my-mysql-instance` in US West 1.

Comment: ahh cool man , got it so i am just wondering the replication lag stuff.. should i be simultaneously creating the cloudwatch alarm to see the replication lag ?

Comment: That's entirely up to you and if you need help setting that up you should create another question showing what you've tried to do to implement that.